# Django Architecture: Where should I schedule a Celery Beat Periodic Task for ALL users?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a `django-celery-beat` periodic task that needs to be run for every user on every Monday of every week. I'm not sure where the right place to create this task is for the first time to schedule it.

I understand that per-user celery tasks can be created wherever in the particular code with `PeriodicTask` and `Interval`, but since this is run for every user I'm not quite sure where it should go or how to instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

periodic_tasks.py

```
# Run every time at 7:30 am on monday.
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1))
def test_hulk_task():
    """First hulk periodic task for testing."""
    logger.log('info', {'event': 'test_hulk_periodic_task'})
```

In settings

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("path.to.periodic_tasks",)
```

Note: If you have not setup celery settings in your project.
Follow this [link](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: Thanks, looks like `django-celery-beat` has an admin tool for creating periodic tasks.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you do not need to create 100 tasks for 100 users. You create 1 task that does X for every user. The fact that you do it for "every user" is not relevant/has no impact on the task definition.

Just do:

```py
@task
def task_foo():
    """Do `bar` to every user."""
    users = get_user_model().objects.all()
    for user in users:
        do_bar(user)
```

If you really want to create 1 task for every user, instead of calling `do_bar()` you could call a separate task, e.g. `task_bar.d(user)`.

Comment: Yeah, this is where my question stems from. When a single user has some kind of one-off task I can schedule it when they sign up. I'm not sure where in my code I should be scheduling a task that is general like what I'm describing. Do I do it on server launch and remove the code after it's scheduled, etc? Do I just check if it exists and ignore it on server launch if it does?

Comment: Celery has something called "Periodic Tasks", so you can create tasks that are triggered automatically on a specific schedule (e.g. every minute, every hour, every day, every week etc). You can define the schedule either through a decorator as @sp1rs were doing, or define it on your Celery python file.
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html